# replacing .each with for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

```
var _this = this,
    fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

this.limitedCollection.each(function(model) {
    fragment.appendChild(_this.renderModel(model)[0]);
});
```

i would like to change the above to loop until maximumDisplayedItems instead of all items in collection.

something like this:

```
var _this = this,
    fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0; i < this.maximumDisplayedItems; i++) {
    // do stuff
};
```

Comment: Why not just have a incremented count in the .each and break; when maximumDisplayedItems number is reached?

Comment: What is limitedCollection? and array?

Comment: you don't need to use a for loop, Backbone and Underscore are all about functional programming and have methods that help you deal with this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.limitedCollection.length && i < this.maximumDisplayedItems; i++) {
    fragment.appendChild(_this.renderModel(limitedCollection[i])[0]);
};
```

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

In case if your `limitedCollection` is `Backbone.Collection` you can access model like:

```
fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var models = this.limitedCollection.models; // array of Backbone.Model objects, 
var modelsLength = models.length;
for (var i = 0; i < modelsLength && i < this.maximumDisplayedItems; i++) {
  fragment.appendChild(_this.renderModel(models[i])[0]);
};
```

Comment: What if `maximumDisplayedItems` is larger than the amount of items in `models`?

Comment: It will fail. I guess @Spdexter should manage it. I will update that case.

Comment: Oh, and you might not want to assume `limitedCollection` is the same as `this.collection.models`.

Comment: I assume that asker is familiar with Backbone. Here I have demonstrated an aprroach for the problem, and it can be named differently.

Comment: you don't need to assume, he's obviously using Backbone since the question is tagged and arrays don't have the `each` method.

Comment: The practice showed that neither tags nor even function's names can't 100% prompt which lib used.

Comment: Dear downvoter, please comment why you assume that this answer is needless :)

Answer (score -2):

just use the collection's `first` method:

```
this.limitedCollection.first(maximumDisplayedItems).forEach(function(model) {
    fragment.appendChild(_this.renderModel(model)[0]);
});
```

or `slice` for paging:

```
var page = 1,
    maximumDisplayedItems = 10,
    start = (page - 1) * maximumDisplayedItems;

this.limitedCollection.slice(start, start + maximumDisplayedItems).forEach(function(model) {
    fragment.appendChild(_this.renderModel(model)[0]);
});
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure `limitedCollection` even has a `first` function? Arrays don't.

Comment: @Cerbrus arrays don't have `each` either...he's obviously using Backbone.js

Comment: i can use .first but i want to loop through - say first 10 items first then next 10 and so on.

Comment: @Spdexter I've added a typical paging implementation that is used in Backbone applications. Try to learn the best practices of the tools you are using and the power of these libraries.